# Excel- How to create a chart with a variable width column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Note: if serverfault is not the proper forum for excel questions then please forward me to the correct forum in stackExchange group.**

I need to create a chart whose columns has different width.

I found this [long work-around](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/variable-width-column-charts/) to do that but:
a. I couldn't adjust it to work in Excel 2010
b. I can't believe that this is the only way to do it in the most useful spreadsheet in now days

I also tried to add the histogram add-in becayse as far as I know graph with variable width of its columns is a histogram- but it completely something else in Excel.

Does someone know how I can generate such chart?

Comment: SuperUser would be a better fit for your question - but DO NOT repost it yet. This question will either be migrated or closed here - in the latters case you can re-ask it on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Excel has no built-in facility for this effect. You need to use a workaround such as I wrote about in that "long work-around".

What part of the protocol doesn't work in Excel 2010?